# Как включить х265?

Tags: ffmpeg

Как включить х265? ОС: Windows 7. Сейчас установлено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что значит: configuration и перечисленные далее флаги и как их применить?

Comment: Все эти флаги были применены в момент инасталяции, для использования: `./ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v libx265 output-video-h265.mp4` [Doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)

Comment: @KostaB., я так сначала попробовал. Однако, ffmpeg возвращает ошибку: unknown decoder 'libx265'